# Jupyter Notebook Save Multiple Plots As One PDF

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Say I have multiple images/plots produced by seaborn or matplotlib in a Python Jupyter Notebook. How do I save all of them into one PDF file in one go?

Comment: You can output each plot as an image, maybe into a new, separate directory, in the course of running your notebook and then at the end of the notebook code a section in using ReportLab or Pillow to iterate on the images in your directory to composite them together as you wish. Both of those packages are capable of saving as PDF as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `matplotlib` you can create `subplots` inside the same `figure`and use `plt.savefig` to save as PDF or PNG. Based on this [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) you can:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some example data to display
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(30, 15))
axs[0, 0].plot(x, y)
axs[0, 0].set_title('Axis [0, 0]', fontsize = 20)
axs[0, 0].set_xlabel('x-label for [0,0] plot', fontsize=18)
axs[0, 0].set_ylabel('y-label for [0,0] plot', fontsize=18)

axs[0, 1].plot(-x, y, 'tab:orange')
axs[0, 1].set_title('Axis [0, 1]', fontsize = 20)
axs[1, 0].plot(x, -y, 'tab:green')
axs[1, 0].set_title('Axis [1, 0]', fontsize = 20)
axs[1, 1].plot(x, 2*y, 'tab:red')
axs[1, 1].set_title('Axis [1, 1]', fontsize = 20)

# .pdf for your case, default .png
plt.savefig(r'yourpath\fig1.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
```

Rearrange your plots how you like and set `figsize` and `fontsize` to make the output PDF readable. Here you'd have this downloaded as single-paged PDF: [image]

Check [here](https://www.statology.org/seaborn-subplots/) for `sns.subplot` and use `savefig` again.

If you want to save figures created in different cells inside your notebook (in seperate PDF pages) try something like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/saving-multiple-figures-to-one-pdf-file-in-matplotlib):

```
fig1= plt.figure(...)
plt.plot(...)
```

```
fig2= plt.figure(...)
plt.plot(...)
```

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
def multiple_figues(filename):
    pp = PdfPages(filename)
    fig_nums = plt.get_fignums()
    figs = [plt.figure(n) for n in fig_nums]
    for fig in figs:
        fig.savefig(pp, format='pdf')
    pp.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

in notebook : file => Download as => PDF ...

or

you can import your file in google drive, and open it with google colab then : file => print => save it as a pdf.